# Oozie: Testing workflows locally

Tags: testing, hadoop, configuration, ide, oozie

Ooozie XML based workflow defintions are error prone and difficult to debug at run time.  Also, running them in a production environment is a bit of a risk.

1) Is there a simple way to test an  oozie based workflow / application ; via an embedded server or other mock environment?

2) Are there any polished IDE / TDD idioms around oozie development?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. MiniOozie might help.
2. Also using -dryrun allows to print the resolved xml of 1 materialization and do syntax check - http://oozie.apache.org/docs/3.3.2/DG_CommandLineTool.html#Dryrun_of_Coordinator_Job

Answer (score 2):

> Also, running them in a production environment is a bit of a risk.

Not sure what the above statement means.

Take a look at MiniOozie test [here](http://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/ENG_MiniOozie.html) for unit testing Oozie workflow and coordinator.

Comment: MiniOozie is buggy and requires many things to run properly: minihdfs, minimr, e.t.c. There are many arguments why MiniOozie should be improved. Did you find solution for your qestion?